# Can't get example JAVA code for JFileChooser to work in NetBeans IDE 8.2

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I am trying to write a program that will prompt the user to select a folder and will then allow the user to display all the contents within the folder.  I've been searching the webs and found several examples of using JFileChooser, including this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083447/selecting-folder-destination-in-java).  When I try to use the example in the previous link in JGrasp, it runs without issue.  However, when I try to run it in NetBeans, I get errors (The DemoJFileChooser class won't compile because a return type is required, and the line in Main says can't find symbol DemoJFileChooser).  I'm not sure what the issue is with it, but I've adapted it the best I can below

The below program compiles and runs fine, but when I select option 1, the program just freezes for a second, and then re-displays the menu.  I can't get it to display the file selection dialog.  What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class FileDirectoryProcessing {

JFileChooser chooser;
String choosertitle;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SelectionMenu:
    while (true) {
        Scanner scannerIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("0 - Exit");
        System.out.println("1 - Select Directory");
        System.out.println("2 – List directory contents");
        System.out.println("Select Option");
        try{
        int userInput = Integer.parseInt(scannerIn.nextLine());
        switch (userInput) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("Thank you");
                break SelectionMenu;
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Select a directory");

                new FileDirectoryProcessing().ChooseDirectory();
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Directory Contents");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Please make a valid selection");
                break;
        }

        } catch (NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("Please make a valid selection");
        }           
    }      
}

private void ChooseDirectory(){
    chooser = new JFileChooser(); 
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
    chooser.setDialogTitle(choosertitle);
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

    chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { 
      System.out.println(chooser.getCurrentDirectory() 
         +  "getCurrentDirectory(): ");
      System.out.println("getSelectedFile() : " 
        +  chooser.getSelectedFile());
      }
    else {
      System.out.println("No Selection ");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you try `chooser.showOpenDialog(new javax.swing.JFrame());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `showOpenDialog` accepts a component, whereas `this` (instance of `FileDirectoryProcessing`) is not a component, hence the issue.

Provide parent `component` instance in the method. Or for now you can also pass `chooser` (instance of `JFileChooser`) or `null` as well.

So, both of the below options will work fine:

```
chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser)
```

or

```
chooser.showOpenDialog(null)
```

Comment: Hi Aman, this worked great.  My program is at least compiling now, but the filechooser pane isn't appearing.  I played around for a moment, and found it when I minimized all my other windows.  It is popping up in the back.  I looked through the methods to see if I could set it in the front, but I didn't find anything.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @skidwiz That already has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129294/bringing-jfilechooser-on-top-of-all-windows