# jQuery Directory chooser Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not pretty sure if I can accomplish what I need with pure jquery but maybe you guys can help me out.

I need to give the user the opportunity to browse his local computer to choose a location where some files will be saved( the download and saving functionality is handled via a jsp page) but the process of choosing the destination should be done in jquery.

Is this possible ?

I've found some plugins, but they all seem to be server side only.

Comment: [this post may help you]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942436/how-to-get-folder-directory-from-html-input-type-file-or-any-other-way

Comment: thanks I've already stumpled upon this, but I cannot limit it to chrome use only...

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible. Javascript in a browser does not have access to file system api's. The absolute best you can do to interact with the file system is accept a `'drop'` event from drag and drop, or use `<input type="file" />`.