# Load all files from a directory in JavaScript/HTML5

Tags: javascript, flash, html

I want visitors of my websites to select a directory with files and then process them in JavaScript. I know how to let them select lots of individual files but not whole directories, which is pretty important here.

How can it be done? The processing of the files must be done in JavaScript. It should work in newest Firefox, Chrome and, if possible, IE.

I cannot tell them to zip the files and then select the zip since it can be a few GB of files to process.

Maybe Flash could help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get folder directory from HTML input type "file" or any other way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942436/how-to-get-folder-directory-from-html-input-type-file-or-any-other-way)

Comment: @LJ_1102 Thanks, but it was 2 years ago and wasn't solved.

Comment: @Tom since you mentioned Flash:  See [this](https://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_and_Adobe_Flash_controversy)

Comment: @Meredith Thanks, I know that but I would rather have something that works with Flash than doesn't work at all :)

Comment: @Tom do you want to do this server-side or client-side? If server-side you could check out NodeJS's file API

Comment: @Meredith It has to be client side as this is a few GB of data on the client's computer, so no, PHP/NodeJS is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found that looking for an example myself, but I did not explore the source yet. Works on Chrome on Windows 8.1. Hope this helps someone.

[HTML5 Photo Browser for Local Files and Directories](http://techslides.com/html5-photo-browser-for-local-files-and-directories)

It uses:

\< input type="file" id="file_input" webkitdirectory="" directory="">