# 'Browse for Folder' widget

Tags: gwt, directory

I can find tons of off-the-shelf GWT widgets that let me [select browse directories and select files](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwFileUpload) but I can't find a single GWT widget that'll help me select a directory (similar to how Google drive does it).

Can any one here help me out with this ?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible in GWT, because there's (currently) no browser agnostic way to do this with HTML/JavaScript.

See this related question:

[Directory Chooser in HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809688/directory-chooser-in-html-page)

---

However, there apparently is a way to get this working in just Chrome (or more specifically webkit) as discussed here:

[How to get folder directory from HTML input type "file" or any other way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942436/how-to-get-folder-directory-from-html-input-type-file-or-any-other-way)