# Uploading files from client side using VBScript and Python

Tags: python, vbscript, activex

I have a webpage which I run in IE8.

It uses VBScript to copy files from my machine to server. It basically copies all files from that folder.

The top of the code is like this:

```
set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set oObj = oFS.GetFolder(folderPath)
set files = oObj.Files
....
....
```

Using `files` object, I traverse to individual files.

But when I put this code in a server, it asks permission to activate `ActiveX Controls`.

And if a user doesn't have admin rights, then ActiveX is disabled and they are stuck.

I basically get this error : `ActiveX component can't create object: 'Scripting.FileSystemObject'`

So if I move my code to `Python` at the backend (we are planning for `Python` as VBScript is not supported by modern browsers, not even IE11), still I'll have to access users local folder through our code.

Maybe I can access the local files using a method from `Python`'s `os` library: `os.listdir()`

Will I again face the same problem of `ActiveX Controls`?

If not, please suggest why?

Thank You.

Comment: So you you want to access the filesystem of someone who views your webpage in his browser?

Comment: @tobifasc The webpage has an `<input>` tag, where the user can browse for a file in a folder.

Comment: Maybe look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942436/how-to-get-folder-directory-from-html-input-type-file-or-any-other-way

Comment: @Martijn Pieters : Could you please help me understand this. Thanks.

Comment: Who is Martijn Pieters? Here is a good example on how you can do it with php. Adapt it for your needs: http://earlysandwich.com/programming/how-to-upload-multiple-files-or-folders-with-html-and-php-168/

Comment: But i can't seem to get it working in firefox and IE...