# How to select the folder level in jsp?

Tags: html, jsp

```
<input type="file" name="location">
```

by this way it will select the file level, not in directory level. how to achieve in directory level. Thanks

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942436/how-to-get-folder-directory-from-html-input-type-file-or-any-other-way

Comment: It won't. You cannot select a folder using the file input control -- you can select a file.