# Folder Choose in Html

Tags: html

I just want users select folder path.

For example;

User choose 'D:/example/' folder.

Then im save 'D:/example/' to my database.

```
<input type='file'> doesnt work for me . I just need folder path
```

How can i do that ?

Edit:
[Everyone show this for answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942436/how-to-get-folder-directory-from-html-input-type-file-or-any-other-way)

but this is not my question. It listing directory.

I just want folder path like d:/asd/  user pick asd folder on d.

so i save my database to 'd:/asd/' .just this

I dont know how can i explain more.

Comment: The question makes no sense. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: A far better and more detailed explanation of problem is definitely needed. Have no idea what you are trying to do

Comment: i dont know how can i explain different way . Its very simple. When users click browse button in the site i want them select folder not file

Comment: Please note that for obvious security reasons browser won't give local directory information on `file` input

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942436/how-to-get-folder-directory-from-html-input-type-file-or-any-other-way

Comment: *"When users click browse button in the site i want them select folder not file"* - That is up to the person at the other end to do that, not you.

Comment: i will use it on localhost. Is there any way to do that ? @charlietfl

Comment: Can do it with flash ( or used to be able to anyway)

Comment: that possible duplicate posted up there seems to only work with Chrome.

Comment: also I think html5 droppable supports dragging directory

Comment: @txtechhelp this is listing folder. i dont want this. I just want user select a folder like first example.

Comment: The question is clear, why did you give down vote? also maybe this answer help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809688/directory-chooser-in-html-page?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @Tunaki the question makes perfect sense and it is exactly what I am looking for

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I hope this can help you

you can see the folder name in alert when select a file

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getfolder(e) {
    var files = e.target.files;
    var path = files[0].webkitRelativePath;
    var Folder = path.split("/");
    alert(Folder[0]);
  }
</script>

<input type="file" id="flup" onchange="getfolder(event)" webkitdirectory mozdirectory msdirectory odirectory directory multiple />
```

Comment: Thanks. Its worked. But only ie . didnt work at chrome

Comment: Does it work on mobile phone?

Comment: @AmanullahAman I've tried, but from Chrome mobile it isn't working... The file selector opens, but then no alert shows...