# Getting path directory from input file ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I read up on how to get a file input to select a directory, link here [how to get folder directory from html input type file or any other way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942436/how-to-get-folder-directory-from-html-input-type-file-or-any-other-way)

Now the issue I have is to get the list of files it picks up from the directory:
[folder count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G80qp.jpg)

OR

Get the directory path in the backend of the ASP.Net when the user clicks on the submit button.

The code:

```
// POST: /Gallery/CreateImage
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateImage(FormCollection collection, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{

    try
    {
        //For each file in folder do the following
        string title = collection["title"];
        string description = collection["description"];
        bool isSlide = collection["isSlider"] == "on" ? true : false;
        bool isGallery = collection["isGallery"] == "on" ? true : false;

        gallery = new Gallary(title, description, Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).Replace(".",string.Empty), isSlide, isGallery, Category.Drawing);

        gallery.AddToGallery(gallery, file);

        return View("GalleryManage", "Gallery");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View("GalleryManage", "Gallery");
    }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateFolder", "Gallery", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <p>Please make sure that your folder structure is in the following format:</p>
                <ol>
                    <li>Root Folder</li>
                    <li>-Art Category Folder</li>
                    <li>--Project Folder</li>
                    <li>---Images</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="file">Please choose root folder</label>
                <input type="file" name="folderUpload" webkitdirectory directory multiple />
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="box-footer">
                <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: You cant get the full path of the file (for security reasons) Earlier versions of IE did include it but that as now been removed)

Comment: Is there a way to get the files?

Comment: Are you posting a single file or multiple files? How have you generated the file input in the view (what is the `name` attribute). You need to show the relevant code (and why in the world are you using `FormCollection` instead of your model)

Comment: I added the HTML code as well

Comment: You have a multiple file input named `folderUpload` so your POST method needs to be `public ActionResult CreateImage(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> folderUpload)` - and then you can just loop through each file in the collection. And not sure if you just omitted some of the view, but your not posting anything for `title`, `description etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user3559349 points out in the comments.

I changed the CreateImage method post to `ActionResult CreateImage(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> folderUpload)`.

I was able to get all the images uploaded.