# Enable ask to save download file using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: Chrome Setting]

I want to set the above setting (Ask where to save each file before downloading) using javascript or jquery

Comment: You need to find some another option as its not possible with `javascript` and `JQuery`

Comment: it would be quite unsafe to let developers modify client browser settings via javascript

Comment: okay.  Then how to make user to select his own file download location using javascript/jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's browser configuration that you can't change.

Also there is not possible to select folder as `<input type="file">` value ([exception for Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942436/how-to-get-folder-directory-from-html-input-type-file-or-any-other-way))

Comment: okay.  Then how to make user to select his own file download location using javascript/jquery

Comment: @LakhanBaheti js does not have access to browser settings. I think it may be even security issue if it would.