# get folder directory from input type file - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

just a quick question,

mission is to get a folder directory name. example: _C:\ThisFolder\myFolder_.

and I've used html input type="file" but I'm only able to get the file name, plus type="file" works like one want to upload something, while I just want to get the folder path of user selection.

```html
<label> Update to  : </label>
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="dirpath" name="dirpath" directory />
```

is there any other approach that I could use, please advice,
thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can do that due to security reasons.

Comment: You can select directory by file input and get folder name. Here is an example https://www.askingbox.com/question/html5-get-folder-name-from-file-input

Comment: This perfectly answers your question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)

Comment: New in 2022 - See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73713676/1909132

Answer (score 2):

Due to security reasons browser does not allow it. Browser has no access to the file system. If you need the file's path for reading a file you can use the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) API instead.

Comment: what I need is something like selecting a folder to save file before begin downloading it? can't I do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```js
   
     $('#dirpath').on('change',function ()
            {
                var filePath = $(this).val();
                console.log(filePath);
            });
```

```html
<label> Update to  : </label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="dirpath" onchange="fileget(event)" name="dirpath" directory />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: gives me this error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null**

Comment: did you insert the jquery ?

Comment: sorry, my bad..it does working, but what I need is something like selecting a folder to save file before begin downloading it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just use it like this:

```
<label> Update to  : </label>
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="dirpath" name="dirpath" directory onSubmit = getPath()/>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function getPath() {
     var inputName = document.getElementById('dirname');
     var Path;

     Path = inputName.value;
}
</script>
```