# How to select an empty directory in ReactJS?

Tags: html, reactjs, file-upload, directory

I want to select an empty directory/folder(not any file) for my project . I've tried

`<input directory="" webkitdirectory="" type="file"/>`

This selects the files inside the directory and shows the files which were selected.

If i select an empty directory, since there are no files inside it, after selection it shows 'No file chosen'

I want to select  only an empty directory(not any files). How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in control in any mainstream browsers that would allow a user to easily select a folder. The closest thing there is would be `<input type="file">`, but that only allows you to select a single file in a folder, not the folder itself.

The only other thing you can do is to create a control that the user will have to approve of before they can use it.

**Found the above answer from https://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=5201**

Answer (score -1):

I think this Question is a Duplicate for this [one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942436/how-to-get-folder-directory-from-html-input-type-file-or-any-other-way), however, you can select and have access to fold by using this browser API

```
sync function pickDirectory() {
  const selectedDirectory = await window.showDirectoryPicker();

  // run code for selectedDirectory
}
```

> [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/xozvprdj/)

Comment: The answer doesn't solve the problem. The input doesn't select anything as the directory is empty.