# What is the function of the directory attribute in the html input tag?

Tags: html, input, upload

I was looking for a way to enable users to upload folders to a webpage. While I have already found out that this can be achieved with the `webkitdirectory` attribute of the input tag, I stumbled across something I don't understand. Many answers (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16774922/11316364)), also include a `directory` attribute in the `input` tag. Like so:

```
<input type="file" webkitdirectory directory multiple/>
```

I was not able to find documentation on the `directory` attribute, and playing around with it myself, it didn't seem to do anything. What is its function, and do I need to include it?

Comment: here it is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory

Comment: For now tag directory doesn't exist.