# Choose path of folder using HTML or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function in JavaScript that implements download.
One of the parameter that the function get is path - where to download the file.

I want to enable user to choose the path from his computer where to download by a - browse button.

isn't good, it expects to select an actual file, I want only path of folder.

Any idea how to do that using HTML or JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Directory Chooser in HTML page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809688/directory-chooser-in-html-page)

Comment: Even if you can choose the path, there is no way you can set this as the place where the file will be downloaded to. You will have to create custom download manager and have the user install it.

Comment: I have function that doing the download . I just have to send the path as paramter.

Comment: But it won't work. Anyway it doesn't matter, as correctly said in the linked duplicate HTML and/or JavaScript do not support choosing a directory.