# folder picker in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, directory

In my html5 webapp using jquery, I want the user to choose a local directory name.
The `<input  type="file">` element is close, but I want to choose a folder instead of a file.

fwiw, I need the path too, which I'm guessing may not be possible.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809688/directory-chooser-in-html-page

Comment: after all my searching too! thanks for the link. i will rethink the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be possible with the new [FileSystem Api](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/) but the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/filesystem) is currently pretty bad. Seems like the only supported browsers are using the webkit engine. Everything else including Firefox won't work. So i would go with "No it isn't possible yet."