# How can I create save destination chooser of file with GWT?

Tags: gwt

I want to enhance [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988153/file-destination-chooser/20988290?). How can I create File Destination Chooser (as like [JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)) in GWT?

I had googled for a long time to get it in GWT. I found [GWT FileUpload](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FileUpload.html) in most.
Any Suggestions for it ?

Comment: previous my question is only for java. sorry ! really I want to create it in GWT project. So , I can't tag [Tag:java] again. I don't want to use Swing or Applet.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: After clearing on question

Well, for this you would need a Download Servlet for the file. There in HttpServletResponse you will fill the content with the file and header with file types and all.

And from your client side call the URL.

For prompting case, it depends upon the browser configuration. You cannot force browser to open location prompt.

For achieving download only, you can refer to [download file using gwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725198/how-can-a-user-download-a-file-in-client-side-google-web-toolkit)

Comment: see http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Widgets~FileUpload
You can see the usage there

Comment: sir ! I don't understand . I am not asking about uploading a file. I mean saving file. Eg: when user click on save buttion , Save destination chooser dialog will appear.

Comment: yes , that is useful facts for me. But I want to create customize widget for it. You can see *Java JFileChooser* can get. I exactly know what is your answer meaning because I had did in some case of my project.eg: download user information as MS Excel file or pdf or text file.

Comment: that I meant for the file upload case. I didn't get the question properly earlier