# Get directory path by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

To choose the file type there is a Certain input

```
<input type="file" id="theFile" />
```

but I do not want to choose the file, I want to choose a folder from the I?

Comment: So you want to know what folder the file is coming from?  What do you plan on using the path for?

Comment: a folder from the what ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809688/directory-chooser-in-html-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simply not possible. You can only choose files, but not folders (all files in a folder is fine though).

To select multiple files, use `multiple`:

```
<input type="file" name="whatever" multiple>
```

Comment: grateful for the help ^ ^ but how would I take the array with the addresses of the images

I would like to open the window and retrieve the images without using an input

Answer (score 0):

The 'file' input type is for just-as-it-reads -- selecting a FILE, not a DIRECTORY.

Comment: I would like to open the window and retrieve the images without using an input