# FolderBrowserDialog with MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, folderbrowserdialog

Is there anything like FolderBrowserDialog to be used with MVC 4? I want to be able to press a button e.g. "Browse" in the browser, get a dialog where I could choose a folder on the server, and get the selected folder path in the controller's action method.

Thanks.

Comment: Generally, [it's not possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2809706/1180426) in HTML & Javascript only.

Comment: @Satpal Doesn't look like a duplicate to me...

Comment: Retracted my close vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try  [Elfinder Connector](https://elfinderaspnet.codeplex.com/). It's working perfectly for me.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think this File Manager can let me do what I need i.e. select a folder only?