# html5/Javascript - How to get the Selected folder name?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using webkitdirectory to select a folder. I want to get the folder name which is selected for uploading.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

html:

```
<input type="file" id="FileUpload" onchange="selectFolder(event)" webkitdirectory mozdirectory msdirectory odirectory directory multiple />
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectFolder(e) {
    var theFiles = e.target.files;
    var relativePath = theFiles[0].webkitRelativePath;
    var folder = relativePath.split("/");
    alert(folder[0]);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have noticed one limitation in above solution. If you have a `blank` folder then it doesn't work. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @MKR what do you mean by blank folder? I'm not familiar with Mac or Linux, but I can't rename a folder to just spaces, or an empty string, which is what I take "blank" to mean.

Comment: @donutguy640 Suppose I have created a folder "ABC". That "ABC" folder does not contains any other files yet. In that scenario you cannot select the folder name.

Comment: @MKR You are right. In new update of google chrome, it is not selecting a folder if it is empty.

Comment: what happen if directory is empty and need the path???