# Select shared folder HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, networking

I want to allow user to select a folder to store documents using HTML5, I found this snippet to be helpful:

```
 <input type="file" id="FolderSelect" webkitdirectory mozdirectory msdirectory odirectory directory multiple />
```

But this is not showing the shared folders under Network.
[image: Folder Select Popup]

How could I allow users to select a shared folder?

Comment: Where did you get that code from? It might help if we knew what you were referencing.

Comment: I took that snippet from [Get Selected Folder Name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718769/html5-javascript-how-to-get-the-selected-folder-name)