# Calling a "function" inside a TypeScript file to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular, typescript

I'm fairly new to HTML, TypeScript, and JavaScript. I'm currently trying to get the relative path from a selected folder. I'm using code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718769/html5-javascript-how-to-get-the-selected-folder-name) Stack post. I've added the HTML for selecting a folder but I'm having trouble with the JavaScript portion. This is an Angular 2 app so I have a TypeScript file. I've added my code below as well as a JSFiddle link after it.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" style="border-color: #464646;">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="border-color: #BBBBBB; height: 35px; padding-top: 3px;">
        <div style="float: left; margin-top: 5px;">Select directory</div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <!--Directory Selection Button-->
        <div class="row">
            <input type="file" id="FileUpload" onchange="selectFolder(event)" webkitdirectory mozdirectory msdirectory odirectory directory multiple />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my TypeScript file:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: './SDI/templates/home.html',
})
export class HomeComponent {

    constructor(){ }

    selectFolder(e: any) {
        console.log('selectFolder entered.'); 

        var theFiles = e.target.files;
        var relativePath = theFiles[0].webkitRelativePath;
        var folder = relativePath.split("/");
        alert(folder[0]);
    }
}
```

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/roka545/9ufc5nsg/

However, when I run the application and select a folder, my console tells me

```
selectFolder is not defined.
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `(change)` instead of `onchange` attribute. Basically `onchange` event looks for function in global javascript `scope`(context), whereas when you wanted to call `Component` method associated with template, you have to follow `(eventName)`(event name in paranthesis) convention to call component `function`.

Additionally do use `$event` while passing parameter to function instead of `event`.

```
(change)="selectFolder($event)"
```

Comment: Thanks. That eliminates the console error, but now the 'console.log' line within selectFolder() doesn't run. Is there something wrong with the actual selectFolder() function as well?

Comment: `$event` instead of just `event`

Comment: @CoreyOgburn oh.. Thanks for heads, I completely missed that part, Cheers & Thanks :)

Comment: @PankajParkar I've added the changes you and CoreyOgburn suggested but selectFolder() still isn't being called. JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/roka545/9ufc5nsg/

Comment: @Roka545 because you have error in console, related to `require`

Comment: Scratch that - it works perfectly fine inside my Visual Studio project. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Roka545 Cool, interesting thing is you made Angular Fiddle, that's awesome, generally people do use plunkr. Thanks & Cheers :)

Comment: @Roka545 I quess it should work in Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6nfa7nsa/