# Control to browse/select only a folder, not a file in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have an import form on my asp.net page. There are 2 browse controls. The first allows the user to select a file (typical). For the second one I want the user to be able to select a folder/dir (because I want to import all files in that directory.) How can I do this? Currently I'm using this but it only works with files. I want the user to only be able to select a folder....

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="DirUpload" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Cannot be done using conventional means. Might be possible using a third party component or hacks.

See this question: [Directory Chooser in HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809688/directory-chooser-in-html-page)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do like this:
(i am posting answer with mobile so excuse me for misspelling)

```
aspx code 

<asp:FileUpload ID="fuImages" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" /> <asp:Button ID="btnUploadImages" Text="Upload Images" runat="server" OnClick ="UploadMultipleImages" accept ="image/gif, image/jpeg" /> <br /> <asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" />
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void UploadMultipleImages(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in fuImages.PostedFiles)
 { string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName); postedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Gallery/") + fileName); }
 lblResult.Text = string.Format("{0} files have been uploaded successfully.", fuImages.PostedFiles.Count); }
```

Comment: The `AllowMultiple` attribute lets you select multiple files, does not allow you to select a "folder" entity.

Comment: Yeah, so u can select all items in a folder instead of selecting a folder, i think it's same as @WebDevGuy2 wants.