# Wicket: user uploaded directory

Tags: javascript, html, upload, directory

I need to figure out how to have the user select a directory. Closest thing I've found is to have a file upload dialog and then getting the absolute path to the file, but of course that's not the same as selecting a directory instead. Is there a tool for this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to find a browser solution first:

[Directory Chooser in HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809688/directory-chooser-in-html-page)

Then you can ask how to integrate your solution in Wicket.