# File explorer, store path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I want to use a file explorer in order to get the path of the element I'll select in this explorer.

Could I use something like this :

```html
<input type="file"  webkitdirectory />
```

The problematic is :

I would ideally like to limit the selection to folders only, not files.

I want to retrieve the path of the selected folder in order to store it. (I'm using angularjs, so I was thinking of binding it through a model)

Is this possible or is there an alternative suiting my needs ?

Comment: you can't do this from the browser side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it unless you use Java applet or Flash.

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2809706/4185234) answer for details.

> Selecting a file for upload is the best you can do, and even then you
>   won't get its full original path in modern browsers.
>
> You may be able to put something together using Java or Flash (e.g.
>   using SWFUpload as a basis), but it's a lot of work and brings
>   additional compatibility issues.