# How to select a directory and return the folder name using javascript?

Tags: javascript, directory

I need to have a button to select a directory from local disk and then then returns the selected folder name using Javascript? Does anyone have some ideas?

PS: my code is only running on the client.

Comment: You can't [access the file system or full file paths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav) from the client.

Comment: Hi, my code is running on the client. I only know how to select files and get filenames. But for directory, I have no idea.

Comment: @FelixKling I don't need to get the filenams. Instead, I just need to choose a directory, that's it.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you can select folders in JS/HTML/DOM. So it's simply not possible. What do you want to do with the name anyway? *edit*: Well, `<input type="file" />` is the only way to access the file system. If it doesn't allow you to access folders, then bad luck.

Comment: @Ng2-Fun That's what I'm saying. You can't get access to the path of the file (i.e, the directory it's in). You can select multiple files in a directory on some browsers but you won't have access to the directory name.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809688/directory-chooser-in-html-page

Comment: @FelixKling: I need the folder path, and send it to another app for saving files.

Comment: @MikeCluck you can now with HTMLInputElement.webkitdirectory