# Select folder instead of single file - input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the input type to be folder and not a single file. How can I select a folder instead of just a single file. Also how can I then access each file in that selected folder. I tried this to select a folder but didn't work. I am on chrome.

```
 <input id="myInput" type="file" style={{visibility: 'hidden'}} webkitdirectory directory multiple/>
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Directory Chooser in HTML page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809688/directory-chooser-in-html-page)

Comment: Didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 13):

You are looking for the `files` property, which returns a **filelist**.
Use `length` to get the number of `files` then use a `for` statement to do the same for all `files`, increasing the count by 1 each time

```js
var folder = document.getElementById("myInput");
folder.onchange=function(){
  var files = folder.files,
      len = files.length,
      i;
  for(i=0;i<len;i+=1){
    console.log(files[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
 <input id="myInput" type="file" webkitdirectory directory multiple>
```

Comment: I am on linux. I tried your solution but still I am not able to select a folder. It takes me inside the folder only.

Comment: only select folder and then press ok

Comment: There is no "ok". There is an open and a Close button. That's it

Comment: @ApurvG please screenshot

Comment: "open" is a "ok". But I'm seeing that it does not retrieve the files :/ wait

Comment: When I click open, I takes me inside that folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144148/discussion-between-apurvg-and-avril-alejandro).

Comment: [please read this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=59818) (answers 12, 15, 24, 29). This is working on windows

Comment: Thanks @avril for the help.

Comment: Can I make multiple file selection in linux? How?

Answer (score 0):

For this to work on Linux you can use,

```
<input type="file" id="folder" webkitdirectory="" directory="" multiple/>
```