# Closing the div tag making form unusable

Tags: html, node.js, forms

I am creating a form using HTML with the NodeJs backend.
The form is not submitting if I close one of the `div` tag. This is really weird and if I keep it open then it is submitting fine.
I have spend a lot of time in this and I am unable to see where I am doing wrong. I have counted all the `div` multiple times but the count is coming to be fine.
Below is my HTML form -

```
<% layout('layouts/boilerPlate') %>
<h1 class="text-center mb-3">Experiment Detail</h1>
<div class="col-6 offset-3">
    <form action="/plannerHome" method="POST" class="classification" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <div class="classifications">
            <label class="form-label" for="taskName">Experiment name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="taskName" id="taskName" required>
        </div>
    <!-- The closing tag of this div is causing problem --> 
        <div class="classifications">
            <label class="form-label" for="taskType">Experiment Type: </label>
            <select name="taskType" id = "taskType">
                <option value="None">Please Select a Experiment type</option>
                <option value="classify">Classification</option>
                <option value="instance-segmentation">Instance Segmentation</option>
                <option value="semantic-segmentation">Semantic Segmentation</option>
                <option value="localisation">Localisation</option>
            </select>
        <!--</div> This is causing problem -->
    <!-- For the Supplementary material to revise -->
        <div class="classifications">
            <label class="form-label" for="dataManual">Supplementary material: </label> 
            <input class="form-control" type="file" id="dataManual" name="dataManual">
        </div>  
    <!-- For the input file -->
        <div class="classifications">
            <label class="form-label" for="labelFile">Label file: </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="file" id="labelFile" name="labelFile" >
        </div>  
    <!-- Upload file folder : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43958335/select-folder-instead-of-single-file-input-->  

        <div class="classifications"> 
            <label class="form-label" for="data">Data: </label>
            <input class="form-control mb-3 " type="file" id="data" name="data">
        </div>

    </form>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <button>Create Experiment</button>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: "`<select name="taskType" id = "taskType">`" - Odd syntax. I didn't think HTML allowed spaces there. It's a shot in the dark, but what happens if you remove the spaces surrounding the `=` in the `id` attribute?

Comment: I removed it. It is still the same.

Comment: @amphetamachine that is perfectly valid HTML syntax. Here is some more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064095/spaces-between-html-attributes-and-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues I see here.

1. You are not closing the `input` tags which are self-closing tags.
2. THE PROBLEM: The button is not within the form and you are not attaching the click event in the button to your form - or at least not in the included form.

Here is a revised and working version of your code

```html
<% layout('layouts/boilerPlate') %>
<h1 class="text-center mb-3">Experiment Detail</h1>
<div class="col-6 offset-3">
    <form action="/plannerHome" method="POST" class="classification" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <div class="classifications">
            <label class="form-label" for="taskName">Experiment name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="taskName" id="taskName" required />
        </div>
    <!-- The closing tag of this div is causing problem --> 
        <div class="classifications">
            <label class="form-label" for="taskType">Experiment Type: </label>
            <select name="taskType" id="taskType">
                <option value="None">Please Select a Experiment type</option>
                <option value="classify">Classification</option>
                <option value="instance-segmentation">Instance Segmentation</option>
                <option value="semantic-segmentation">Semantic Segmentation</option>
                <option value="localisation">Localisation</option>
            </select>
        </div><!-- This is causing problem -->
    <!-- For the Supplementary material to revise -->
        <div class="classifications">
            <label class="form-label" for="dataManual">Supplementary material: </label> 
            <input class="form-control" type="file" id="dataManual" name="dataManual" />
        </div>  
    <!-- For the input file -->
        <div class="classifications">
            <label class="form-label" for="labelFile">Label file: </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="file" id="labelFile" name="labelFile" />
        </div>  
    <!-- Upload file folder : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43958335/select-folder-instead-of-single-file-input-->  

        <div class="classifications"> 
            <label class="form-label" for="data">Data: </label>
            <input class="form-control mb-3 " type="file" id="data" name="data" />
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <button type="submit">Create Experiment</button>
        </div> 
    </form>
</div>
```