# Upload folder in Angular 4

Tags: angular, filechooser

I'm working on a rest Angular-Java application. Client side (Angular), I want the user to be able to choose a folder, to decide where his file (csv format) will be saved. Server side (Java), it will retrieve this path as a string, and export this file to the desired location.

My question is very simple: Angular Side, how to open a file Chooser to load a folder and return its absolute path?

I know how to open a File Chooser with Java, it's very easy. But i don't know how to proceed with Angular.
I've just found this trick (but it's to upload a file, not a folder) :

```
<input type="file"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not "possible" with the simple HTML way.

I said possible in quotation marks because *[it seems there is a way to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26019091/2724204)* with:

```
<input type="file" webkitdirectory directory multiple/>
```

Anyway, scripting seems inevitable.

There is some very good and well-documented libraries for upload handling with Angular like [ngx-uploader](https://github.com/bleenco/ngx-uploader).

Related topic: [Directory Chooser in HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809688/directory-chooser-in-html-page)

Comment: getting confirmation alert message while uploading folder by using the above code do you know how to avoid that