# How to provide "get directory link" via input

Tags: javascript, html

When having this tag in form

```
<input type="file" webkitdirectory directory multiple />
```

it provides user by a window to chose dir to upload files from

I want the same action but just get the dir without uploading any file

I need it for offline project, so if it needs more authentications no problem.

Comment: Loop these files and gather all dirs provided

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809688/directory-chooser-in-html-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I was sending var on submitting,

yet it shoud be set as array

```
`<button type='submit' name='arr[]' value='submit' multiple>`
```

> Then access it as array