# Choose a directory from user pc with django

Tags: python, django, web

I'm developing a django application (my first time using it) where I need to store a user directory on the database, for that I've extended the user model to add one charfield:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Directory(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    xml_directory = models.CharField()
```

That directory will be later used to iterate between its files.

My problem now is that I cant find how to make the "Alterar" button to open a dialog box for the user to choose the directory. Does anyone have an idea of how I can achieve that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}XML{% endblock title %}
{% block pagename %}Processar XML{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <form action="{% url "save_directory" %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="xml_directory">Local dos Arquivos XML</label>
            <input class="form-control col-6" readonly type="text" id="xml_directory" name="xml_directory" placeholder="{{diretorio_xml}}"></input>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" >Alterar</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Salvar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

Comment: Is this directory a "virtual" directory? Like a directory of files you'd have on a cloud service

Comment: no, a local one like C://Program Files/...

Comment: [Directory chooser in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2809706/18509670) although its there no widely supported option, there are some options that are compatible with more modern browsers. Is there any reason why your server should know a users _local_ directory?